# Syntax error is driving me crazy

Tags: php

I'm trying to write a code that begins at the number 10 and ends at 1 with every odd number adding 1 to the number and every even number subtracting 1 from the number. The code works without `"<br />"` but without it my number are all on the same line and I'm using phpfiddle. The syntax error come when I try to make the numbers each have their own line. Please help I'm going crazy. I'm also new to php and coding in general so please dumb it down so I can understand lol.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
for($i = 10; $i >= 1; $i--) {
    if($i%2 >0) {
        echo $i+1. "<br />" ;
    else {
        echo $i-1. "<br />" ;
    } 
?>
```

Comment: Try `echo ($i+1). "<br />" ;` and `echo ($i-1). "<br />" ;`

Comment: You're missing a bracket before your `else`. Also try putting your expressions inside parenthesis.

Comment: Just remove the two existing `<br>` tags and add a single `echo '<br>';` after the if/else statement.

Comment: that title would probably attract more crazies than you think. It really isn't descriptive.

Answer (score 2):

this is your code, but then with the closing braces and a space between the string concatenations... not sure the result of the code is what you were looking for, but it runs

```
<?php
for($i = 10; $i >= 1; $i--) {
    if($i%2 >0) {
    echo $i+1 . "<br />" ;
    } else {
    echo $i-1 . "<br />" ;
    }
} 
?>
```

Comment: You my friend are a lifesaver. I have no idea what I did wrong, I'm trying to figure it out now.. I've been working on this code for a full week trying to get it to run with each number separately.. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

That's because `1.` is a valid float (number), look:

```
var_dump(1.);
```

outputs:

```
float(1)
```

After a number followed by a dot, the PHP engine expects another number(s) (the precision, unless it is the end of the actual statement). You wrote a string instead. That's an invalid language construct and results in `unexpected (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)` parsing error.

Next time don't concatenate anything when echoing, use `,` instead (which is actually faster):

```
for ($i = 10; $i >= 1; $i--) {
    if ($i%2 >0) {
        echo $i+1 , "<br />" ;
    } else {
        echo $i-1 , "<br />" ;
    }
}
```